# read URL in JTextField (swing) and pass URL to JSoup

Tags: swing, jsoup

the user gives a URL in a JTextField (user interface made with Swing). I then read the URL and pass it to JSoup.
This is my code:

```
private class FileButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String inputLine = input.getText();
            if (inputLine.endsWith("\n")) {
                inputLine = inputLine.substring(0, inputLine.length() - 1);
            }
                        EntrySoup.extractWebpage(inputLine);
        }
    } 

public class EntrySoup {

    public static void  extractWebpage(String inputLine) {
        //The content will be loaded from the URL.

            Document document = null;

            try {
                document = Jsoup.connect(inputLine).get();
            }  catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }


java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: search
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:645)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:541)
    at java.base/java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:488)
    at group4.BasicFrame$WebButtonHandler.actionPerformed(BasicFrame.java:257)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel.setPressed(JToggleButton.java:401)
```

I tried to read the user input, save it in a String variable and pass it to JSoup.

Comment: show us more code to understand the context, the shown code is not enough

Comment: Hint: try to send get request to the two following urls: "http:// google.com"  (omit tihe space after the //) and "google.com". See if there is a difference in the responses.